# Какими библиотеками можно реализовать элементы расположенные вокруг

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть в макет, в котором есть `input` и при вводе в него, вокруг должны появляться элементы, какими библиотеками можно это реализовать? Используется React.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я по быстрому нашёл такой вариант https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-cloud, Но не уверен, что он подойдёт

Answer (score 1):

```js
let index = 0;
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onkeydown = e => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){ // если нажать enter
        let elem = document.createElement('span');
        elem.innerText = input.value;
        input.value = '';
        elem.style.left = 100 * (2 + Math.sin(index)) + 'px';
        elem.style.top = 100 * (2 - Math.cos(index)) + 'px';
        document.body.append(elem);
        index += 0.7;
    }
}
```

```css
input{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #033;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: В css в span ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.